# Encounter error when using TensorFlowLite. The API can not accept the input photo pixel RGB data

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow-lite

We see the following error when try to run TensorFlowLite Demo. We want to use TenserFlowLite on iOS for generate image score by MUSIQ algorithm.

Failed to invoke the interpreter with error: Provided data count 1769472 must match the required count 0.

Did anyone encounter the same error? Any suggestions will be appreciated.